# I want to enable the scrollview in one IBAction then before that action I want to disable it.how can I do this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to enable the scrollview in one IBAction then before that action I want to disable it.how can I do this?

I disable the scrollview from xib but it's not working too

```
-(IBAction)editClick
{
    scrview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(262,textView.contentSize.height+20+imageHeight);
    myView.frame= CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, myView.frame.origin.y, myView.frame.size.width, 5000);
    [scrview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRedraw];
     NSLog(@"scrview content height%f",scrview.contentSize.height);
     //[scrview setNeedsDisplay];
     oneFingerSwipeLeft.enabled=NO;
     oneFingerSwipeRight.enabled=NO;
     swipe=NO;
     //NSLog(@"edit Click");
     //textView.editable= YES;
}
```

And this is my viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    scrview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(262,308);
```

Comment: what do u mean by disable...disable scrolling or user Interaction....

Answer (score 1):

Try this.... In your viewDidLoad

```
your_scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO;
```

Then in you IBAction

```
your_scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
```